# My Godot 4 game is detecting touchpad events as if they were joypad events. How do I disable this?

Tags: joypad, godot4

This is Godot 4 and, as dumb as it looks, this is the code:

```
func _input(event):
    print(event, " in device ", event.device)
```

When playing in debug mode, I see many events like this:

```
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.35 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=0, axis_value=-0.01 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.35 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=0, axis_value=-0.01 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.34 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=0, axis_value=-0.01 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.34 in device 0
InputEventJoypadButton: button_index=0, pressed=false, pressure=0.00 in device 0
InputEventJoypadButton: button_index=3, pressed=true, pressure=0.00 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=0, axis_value=-0.01 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.34 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=0, axis_value=-0.01 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.34 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=0, axis_value=-0.02 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.34 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=0, axis_value=-0.02 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.34 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.34 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=0, axis_value=-0.02 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.34 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.34 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=0, axis_value=-0.02 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.33 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=0, axis_value=-0.02 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.33 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=0, axis_value=-0.02 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=1, axis_value=-0.33 in device 0
InputEventJoypadMotion: axis=0, axis_value=-0.02 in device 0
```

(i.e. moving, moving, moving, slightly pressing the touchpad, moving, moving, moving...)

How do I prevent the touchpad from being recognized as a joypad / gamepad / etc? When I connect joypads (even a virtual one I'm developing), The result of this function:

```
Input.get_connected_joypads()
```

Is `[0, some_id]` where `0` stands for the touchpad and the other id corresponds to a physical joypad or a virtual pad.

In fact, I expect `InputEventMouseMotion` or `InputEventMouseButton` to be triggered from the touchpad. NOT my touchpad being recognized as a joypad in the game.

Any hint on this? I'd like to either:

- Fix whatever is causing my touchpad, in godot, to be recognized as a joypad instead. This is wrong to me, at least. **Please**: Do not suggest me about removing the 0. I'm not sure how stable doing that results.
- From `Input.get_connected_joypads()`, filter which devices do not belong to actual joypads (physical or virtual) and only keep the joypads.

Comment: Have you tried posting this in the Godot forums?

Comment: This could be an issue in Godot that has not been fixed yet https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/59250 "Laptop touchpads are seen as gamepads"

Answer (score 1):

I've been running into this issue myself and it seems to be documented here but has not actually been fixed yet nor any workarounds https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/59250

I think I've come up with a general purpose solution. It seems like trackpads return false with Input.is_joy_known() so I have an input handler which rejects trackpad inputs while accepting real joysticks:

```
func _input(event):
    if not Input.is_joy_known(event.get_device()):
        # Skip trackpad and only support real USB joysticks
        return
    # print("ID=" + str(event.get_device()) + " NAME=" + Input.get_joy_name(event.get_device()) + " KNOWN=" + str(Input.is_joy_known(event.get_device())))
    # Handle the rest of your InputEventJoypadMotion events here
```